# How to catch the error of ng-include loading?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using angular.js and asp.net MVC.

In our web app, if the template cannot be loaded somehow, e.g. invalid query parameter with the template url. The server code will throw an exception, and the exception will be caught by Application_Error() in Global.asax.cs, and Application_Error() will invoke Response.Redirect() to redirect to the request to a customized error page.

But ng-include just includes the error page into the .

How can I have the client redirect to the error page, or popup an error message dialog, when ng-include failed to load the template?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming I understood your question, you'll have to handle client side errors in client side code, like [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler) perhaps..Hth.

Comment: server should not be returning a 200 status response. Sounds like you need to do some more configuration

Comment: Consider using an error inteceptor. See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).